# Running multiple columns through a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there anyway I can run a function like this

`crypto['Price'] = crypto['Ticker'].transform(lambda item: cg.get_price(ids=item, vs_currencies='usd'))`

using the function

`cg.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id(id='bitcoin',vs_currency='usd',from_timestamp='1635505200',to_timestamp='1635548400')`

With three columns for the values `id , from_timestamp , to_timestamp` 
with the columns being

`crypto['Ticker'] , crypto['Dateroundts'] , crypto['Dateround+1ts']`

I basically want to make a new column with a the function above using the three columns as variables and dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apply` with `axis=1` to apply across a row:

```
crypto['Price'] = crypto.apply(lambda x: cg.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id(id=x.Ticker,vs_currency='usd',from_timestamp=x.Dateroundts,to_timestamp=x['Dateround+1ts']), axis=1)
```

You can either use the dot notation or use `x` like a `dict` (with square bracket). Though if the name is not a single alphnumeric word, you can only use `x` like `dict`.

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion, change the values of the arguments to match OPs column names `crypto['Ticker'] , crypto['Dateroundts'] , crypto['Dateround+1ts']`